# Cannot get MiniProfiler to work with Asp.net Webform

Tags: url-routing, webforms, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm new to MiniProfiler and try to get it to work. After doing as the instruction I got stuck with error 405: "The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/Faconnect.Portal/mini-profiler-resources/results' is not allowed."

When I try the directlink:

```
http://localhost/mini-profiler-resources/results?id=b5183613-a22a-4c59-836a-d5f066de30ef
```

It gives me the error: Page not found

So my asumptions is Routing is not worked properly for my website. ( It works when I fire up MiniProfiler demo webforms app)

I have already included the following configs

```
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule1" path="mini-profiler*.js" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule2" path="mini-profiler*.css" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule3" path="mini-profiler*.tmpl" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

I'm working on Windows XP, Visual Studio 2010, Cassini, ASP.net 4

Comment: The issue is very similar to when I try to request to a page that have not MiniProfile.dll added. Any ideas?

Comment: Here's the update, when I create a brand new Website. It works. Even when I copy all the Webconfig from the defected one to the new website. It still works. Guess there must be some problem with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours and hours struggling with this, I find out the reason behind this. My website has the following format

```
http://localhost:9999/App.Module1/...
```

The prolem here is the "." in the Path. It's somehow forbidden by Cassini, or MiniProfiler, I don't know. Remove that little one and the problem solved.